# Can I embed a windows store app inside a classic windows application?

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

I would like to embed a universal windows app into a classic windows application on windows 10. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? I think it depends on what "embed" means. For LOB apps, the app can be deployed without store using side-loading. So if you just want it to be deployed with your classic windows app, that's possible. If you just want to launch the UWP app from your classic windows app, it's also possible.

Comment: I am trying to sandbox my app, Something like the "Assigned access mode" in Windows 10. But for some reason assigned access is not working for me. I would like to let user use only my application. all i am looking to do is to open my application inside a frame in a classic windows application.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. However... depending on what you're trying to do, the information below may help you.

If you just want to get the look and feel of a desktop application, you should be aware that Windows 10 apps (unlike Windows 8 apps) run in non-fullscreen mode by default, and can be resized. Desktop apps in Windows 10 have top-right icons (min/max/resize) that look similar to how UWP apps look in the title bar and top-right icons.

If you're creating a UWP app with XAML, you won't be able to embed it in a desktop application. However, if you're building a Windows 10 app using HTML5 and JavaScript, you could repackage it inside a browser control embedded in a desktop application.

If you're creating a game using a 3rd-party tool such as Unity, you can export it as a Windows desktop application just as easily as exporting to a UWP app for Windows 10. Unity can be used for non-game apps as well, so you could export it to a desktop application today, and still have the option of publish a UWP of the same game/app.

If you were thinking of accessing the full Windows SDK from you UWP app, you won't be able to do so, as you will be restricted by the UWP sandbox. But Windows 10 has made many improvements in helping you get access to many advanced features, e.g. accessing certain locations in the file system, so you may be able to get by with all that UWP has to offer.

If you want to avoid the Windows Store, you may sideload your app, as suggested by an earlier comment.

Hope that helps! :)