# view foreign UWP application inside c# form container

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

Wish to setup .net form application and run uwp universal windows platform inside it like a container. 
Is it possible to control the workflow of the application or its design by manipulating the XAML file while loaded inside .net Form window.

My main question is if i can load uwp application inside c# form.

Appreciate any responses.  //v

Duplicate: [Can I embed a windows store app inside a classic windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031180/can-i-embed-a-windows-store-app-inside-a-classic-windows-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wish to setup .net form application and run uwp universal windows platform inside it like a container.

You could launch UWP application that designed with [`URL Protocol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-app-with-uri) in your .net form application. However, you can't control UWP application with .net form app, and UWP app has its own independent running environment. In other words, they both can not communicate directly. So the .net form can't not be regard as container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply this solution does not work with what am trying todo.

Could i use any code like 

[code]
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);    
                Process p = Process.Start(textBox1.Text);
                p.WaitForInputIdle();
                SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
       
[code] And set the parent of the application to my form

Comment: Do you want to launch uwp app in your .net form ?

Comment: yes that is what am trying todo is it possible